# Application Error: AccessControlException

Tags: java, jsp, applet, japplet

When I called `JApplet` class from `JSP` like this :

```
 <jsp:plugin 
      type="applet" 
      code="Class_Name.class" 
      codebase="classes"  
      width="850 height="850">
 </jsp:plugin>
```

I got an error:

> access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermision"
>   "com.sun.media.jai.disableMediaLib" "write")

**What is the problem? and what can I do to fix it?**

Comment: The problems seems to be that your applet (or a library in it) tries to invoke `System.setProperty("com.sun.media.jai.disableMediaLib", ...)` - and it is not allowed by the security manager used for applets. Search for `System.setProperty com.sun.media.jai.disableMediaLib` returns far too many hits. Can you provide more details on how your applet uses JAI?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16142889/java-viewer-not-working-after-jre-1-7-0-21-update seems related to this question but there have not been accepted answers.

Comment: So i guess i need to sign my applet , you are right , i calld `System.setProperty("com.sun.media.jai.disableMediaLib", "true");` in my applet

Comment: I just found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707715/java-plugin-jai-automatic-installation which could provide help. No experience here though.

Comment: @halfbit: thank you , i found my problem , i should add all jars in Archive in applet tag  , thank you again :)